# how to inistall STS in eclipse(juno)

Tags: eclipse

RT:
inistall url:http://dist.springsource.com/milestone/TOOLS/update/e4.2

is it have easy way to inistall that?

details:

1.Your original request has been modified.
2.Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
3.Cannot satisfy dependency.

Comment: STS is built on eclipse - it's not an extension that you add into eclipse

Comment: I stand corrected, you can install the STS plugins here: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=373167

Answer (score 0):

Open **Eclipse Juno** 
Go to **Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...**
Search for the STS and press **Install**